# Arrays not saved outside of the load function - ActionScript 3 and XML

Tags: arrays, xml, actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

First of all, I'm really sorry I'm asking this again but after reading through the top 3 answers to this problem, none seemed to have given me any resolution.

I'm trying to load in an XML file containing level data into my AS3 game. It's quite simple, the XML is dumped into an array that I've checked through and through - the length, size, and each and every variable inside of it is a-okay.

The only real problem is that my array gets *purged* whenever I refer to it outside of the function. I've read that it's related to asynchronous nature of ActionScript and that I need a separate handler... but, perhaps I am simply an idiot, I do posses such a handler.

Could anyone take a peek at this here piece of code and perhaps bonk me on the head with a big stick as to what I made wrong?

```
package{
import flash.net.URLLoader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class LevelLoader extends MovieClip{

    private var _root:MovieClip;

    public var lvlArray:Array = new Array(); //Tablica (wektor) trzymający nam ułożenie mapy.

    private var xmlFile:XML;// The XML File Holder, duuh.
    private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();//The XML File Loader, duuuh.

    private var variant:int;

    public function LevelLoader(v:int){
        loadXML();
        variant = v;
        trace('Poza: '+lvlArray.length);
    }

    // Dośc vokalidów. Ale przeklejam z starego kodu.
    private function loadXML(file:String = "XMLG.xml"):void
    {
        urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
        urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(file));
    }

    private function parseXML(e:Event):void
    {
        xmlFile = new XML(e.target.data);
        loadArray(variant,xmlFile);
    }

    private function loadArray(vars:int,xmlInput:XML):void
    {
        //trace(xmlInput.lay[vars].children().length());
        var layLength:int = xmlInput.lay[vars].children().length();
        for (var i:int = 0; i<layLength; i++){
            this.lvlArray.push(xmlInput.lay[vars].field[i].@type);
            //trace(xmlInput.lay[vars].field[i].@type);
             }
        saveArray(lvlArray);
        trace('W: '+lvlArray.length);
    }

    private function saveArray(arr:Array):void{
        lvlArray = arr;
    }

}
```

}

P.S. Yes those are comments in mixed Polish and English. Please, make nothing of it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think your array is getting "purged," I think it's possible that you're attempting to reference the array before `parseXML` has been called.

Since you've only posted the code for `LevelLoader`, I'll assume that somewhere else, you're attempting to reference `LevelLoader.lvlArray`. You should hold off on this action until you've received some sort of "complete" or "loaded" event that you will dispatch from your `loadArray` method (there's no real need for your `saveArray` method):

```
package{
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.display.MovieClip;

    public class LevelLoader extends MovieClip{

        private var _root:MovieClip;

        public var lvlArray:Array = new Array(); //Tablica (wektor) trzymajacy nam ulozenie mapy.

        private var xmlFile:XML;// The XML File Holder, duuh.
        private var urlLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();//The XML File Loader, duuuh.

        private var variant:int;

        public function LevelLoader(v:int){
            variant = v;
            trace('Poza: '+lvlArray.length);
        }

        // Dosc vokalidów. Ale przeklejam z starego kodu.
        public function loadXML(file:String = "XMLG.xml"):void
        {
            urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, parseXML);
            urlLoader.load(new URLRequest(file));
        }

        private function parseXML(e:Event):void
        {
            xmlFile = new XML(e.target.data);
            loadArray(variant,xmlFile);
        }

        private function loadArray(vars:int,xmlInput:XML):void
        {
            //trace(xmlInput.lay[vars].children().length());
            var layLength:int = xmlInput.lay[vars].children().length();
            for (var i:int = 0; i<layLength; i++){
                this.lvlArray.push(xmlInput.lay[vars].field[i].@type);
                //trace(xmlInput.lay[vars].field[i].@type);
            }
            trace('W: '+lvlArray.length);

            dispatchEvent(new Event(Event.COMPLETE));
        }

    }
}
```

Wherever you're instantiating `LevelLoader`, you'll want to listen for this event:

```
var lvlLoader:LevelLoader = new LevelLoader(1);
lvlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLevelLoaded);
lvlLoader.loadXML();

private function onLevelLoaded(e:Event):void {
    var lvlLoader:LevelLoader = e.target as LevelLoader;
    lvlLoader.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLevelLoaded);

    // you may NOW reference lvlLoader.lvlArray
    trace(lvlLoader.lvlArray.length);
}
```

Note that I've made the `loadXML` method public so that it may be called *after* you've added the event listener.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, @Marcela, alas I'm afraid it didn't exactly do much.

I'm referencing lvlArray outside of the Loading class (hence the publicity, so I don't have to bother with gets and sets to arrays). Essentially, the main scene code evokes...

    var Level:LevelLoader = new LevelLoader(0);

The entire purpose of this class is so that I can dump the loading code for this single array somewhere all in one neat place, and than later on reference the array when I'm building my level.

Comment: Sorry, your comment is unclear and I don't understand the remaining issue.

Comment: Perhaps I'm writing this in haste or I'm being an idiot, but your suggestion clashes quite hard with what I have insofar, or I'm again, simply retarded.

I'll try to stay it again in a bit more clear manner. In essence, LevelLoader class loads my XML into lvlArray, so that my main class can later take said array (which contains the level data) and mince it to build said level. The LevelLoader class exists so that I have a place to dump -all- the loading code into. I'm trying to avoid, like devil avoids holy water, placing loading code into the main function.

Comment: And just to clear things up, here's a pastebin containing LevelLoader and the Main function. Not the entirety, just the bit referencing lvlArray. http://pastebin.com/8qdzL4Zs

Comment: The example above isn't requiring for the loading code to be placed in the main function, it's only requiring that the Main class wait for the `LevelLoader` to complete the load before attempting to reference the `lvlArray`

Comment: Yeah, I know (after like, reading the first suggestion about 50+ times. Sorry, I've been sitting over this for the last 8 or so hours and my brain is a mush). But as I believe, simply adding an event dispatch at the end of LoadArray won't work. Least, it didn't when I tried it.

Comment: In your pastebin link, I don't see you adding a handler for the event being dispatched. That may be the problem.

Comment: You can't help somebody who refuses all valid answers simply because it doesn't work the way he wants. He doesn't want AS3 to be asynchronous and he doesn't even want to understand what that means so let him deal with it.